# TypeScript: adding import means class can't be found?

Tags: typescript

I'm having problems with multiple files in my TypeScript project, a NodeJS app.

I have a class, `Foo`, in the file *Foo.ts* which has a property, `db`, which I want to be a MongoDB client. The class is declared like so:

```
import mongodb = require( 'mongodb' );
class Foo
{
    public db:mongodb.MongoClient = null;
}
```

If the `require()` isn't there, I get a `Cannot find namespace 'mongodb'` error on the `db` property.

In *another* file, *Bar.ts*, I want to create a reference to the `Foo` class. It's declared like so:

```
/// <reference path="Foo.ts" />
class Bar
{
    public foo:Foo = null;
}
```

However, if the `require()` is in `Foo.ts`, I get the error `Cannot find name 'Foo'`. If the `require()` isn't there, everything works as expected, and `Bar` can access `Foo`

How can I get this to resolve properly? I've tried replacing the `require()` with a `<reference />` pointing to the *mongodb.d.ts*, but I get the error in `Application` again (possibly because the module is declared like `declare module "mongodb"`?). I can't seem to get the right combination to get both `Foo.ts` and `Bar.ts` to compile.

I could just declare `db` as `any`, but I'd love to keep code completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're mixing namespaces and modules (formerly called internal and external modules). Namespaces are used for more traditional, older JavaScript development where you would attach objects to `window`. Modules are used when using a module system like CommonJS. Since this is a Node app, you're using modules.

Foo.ts should look something like this:

```
import mongodb = require('mongodb');
class Foo
{
    public db:mongodb.MongoClient = null;
}
export = Foo;
```

Then, in Bar.ts, instead of using a `<Reference>` tag use another require:

```
import Foo = require('./foo');
class Bar
{
    public foo:Foo = null;
}
```